# How to set a global variable to true when running JEST test cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

In the react app, I'm using relative URLs in fetch() to send API requests to the server. This works well in browser however, when I'm running unit test cases (JEST), isomorphic-fetch throws error saying that only absolute urls are allowed. Is there any way to handle this error? I'm trying to wrap the fetch() function and use it. Something like this:

```
    function customNodeFetch(url, options) {
        var finalURL = (isTesting)? 'http://localhost:3000/' : url;
        return fetch(finalURL, options);
     }
```

Here, I'm not knowing how to set isTesting to true, when running test cases. I tried to put the constant in the configuration. But, it's not working.  Is there any other way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global variables to modify the behavior of your code for unit tests, I would suggest injecting the test values instead. The function you showed in your example already accepts the url as a parameter, so just pass localhost to that function when you are running your tests and a real url when the code is running. By forking the logic just for testing, you're invalidating your unit tests, because they are no longer testing the code flow that your app would take in a real world scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, I'll be using the above function in lot of async action creators where URL will be hard coded and will be relative. So, how will I unit test the async action creators?